# String knots unlocking algorithm

Tags: algorithms

Let say that we have four straight strings called RED, GREEN, BLUE and YELLOW. These strings are tied up randomly. We know the current state of strings (like starting point, where we should start untying from here) and the final state (where current string must be look like after untying them).

Here is a very simple example of the problem:

[image: an example state of puzzle]

At every move, we are allowed to replace only two nearby strings. For example, to solve the shown example of the problem, we should do the following replacements:

1) replace GREEN and YELLOW

2) replace BLUE and GREEN

But in a programmable environment, how can I calculate the movements even on a complex state?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the computer language *Mathematica* and should be moved to the math.stackexchange.

Answer (score 1):

> how can I calculate the movements even on a complex state?

If you know only current and desired states, you can’t—there do exist many non-isomorphic braids even with these conditions fixed. For example, consider two braids below:

[image: Two non-isomorphic braids]

You shoud untangle them differently.